# Running a simple function in JS

Tags: javascript

var list : string[];

```
list = [ "pet", "luscy" ];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{       list.push(list[i]. toLowerCase()); 
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What do you intend to do ?

Comment: You don't need to push.

Comment: @squeekyDave, well we don't know what he wants to do

Comment: @jo_va hehe, yeah, I just assume he is wondering why his function doesnt work :)

Answer (score 2):

**That's an infinite loop**. You are pushing into the same array, `list.length` is being increased each iteration.

If you want to make each string to lowercase; You can use `Array.map`.

```
list = [ "pet", "luscy" ];

list = list.map(l => l.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, but it depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

```
var list = ["pet", "luscy"];
const listLength = list.length;

for (var i = 0; i < listLength ; i++) {
    list.push(list[i].toLowerCase()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
["pet", "luscy"].map(v => v.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are pushing, the length increases and it causes an infinite loop, since you are reading the updated length on each iteration.

store the value as `length = list.length` before operation and use this length if you are planning to update the array in the loop

Also there seems to be a whitespace before the function call.

```
list = [ "pet", "luscy" ];

let length = list.length
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{       list.push(list[i].toLowerCase()); 
}
```

This returns list as [ "pet", "luscy", "pet", "luscy"];
But not sure if this was the original intent.

Comment: The whitespace doesn't do any harm (as does the rest of the weird indentation)